# Unzipping files in PHP with zlib?

Tags: php, zlib, dreamhost

My web site is hosted at Dreamhost and there they only get zlib installed along with PHP. I couldn't figure out how to unzip files with the commom methods from this extension as described here : http://php.net/zlib

Does anyone knows how can I unzip a .gz or .gzip file with zlib extension on PHP? That would save my life!

Answer (score 2):

As written in [zlib's PHP binding introduction](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.zlib.php):

> Version 4.0.4 introduced a fopen-wrapper for .gz-files, so that you can use a special zlib: URL to access compressed files transparently using the normal f*() file access functions if you prefix the filename or path with zlib: when calling fopen(). [...] In PHP 4.3.0, zlib: has been changed to compress.zlib:// to prevent ambiguities with filenames containing ':' characters.

Simply `fopen` your file with `compress.zlib://` prepended, and use it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

[The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.examples.php) gives a pretty good example.

Answer (score 0):

GZip and Deflate are explained in [RFC 1952 (GZip)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1952.html) and [RFC 1950 (Deflate)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html). GZip is just Deflate with a header described there, so you can parse that header to detect where the zLib stream is and decompress it with zLib routines.